# React Native _weakMap2 error

Tags: parse-platform, react-native

I just updated to React Native 0.21, but I am getting an error when I require Parse:

```
var Parse = require('parse/react-native').Parse;
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _weakMap2.default()')
```

I don't believe it has to do with Parse though, as searching the directory, the 'weakMap2' reference is only found inside the [react-proxy](https://github.com/gaearon/react-proxy) package.

Has anyone else experienced this error or found a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue but haven't found a solution yet. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in `react-proxy@1.1.7`.
(Don’t use `2.x`, it’s not related to React Native at all currently!)

You can run `npm install react-proxy@1.1.7` so NPM updates it locally. If you are using `npm@2.x`, you would need to run `npm install react-proxy@1.1.7` inside `node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr` or something like this—check where it is installed and make sure it’s 1.x but up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know the issue but running Parse JS SDK as version 1.6.14 works for me. Have the same error as you when running latest 1.7.1. Hard to trace the error.

`npm i parse@1.6.14 --save`

Comment: doesn't seem to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Have you runned `react-native upgrade` after installing new react version?

Answer (score 0):

I forced `react-proxy` to version `2.0.1` and the error is now gone for me.

Comment: You can track it (or better, help fix it!) in https://github.com/gaearon/react-proxy/issues/50.

Comment: `react-proxy@2.x` has no relationship to React Native. I’m not sure how it could possibly help :-/. I released `1.1.7` which should fix the problem however.